# Declare dynamic result before using statement with Dapper

Tags: c#, dynamic, dapper

I am using Dapper to make a call to a stored procedure. I would like to use the returned record outside of the using statement but I am not sure how to declare the variable `returnedData` as it is dynamic and dependent on the results of the stored procedure. I am only making this call once so it does not make any sense to me to make a model to represent the collection returned by the stored procedure, hence why I wanted to use .

```
using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(SqlDataAccess.LoadConnectionString("TestData")))
{
    var returnedData = db.Query<dynamic>("StoredProcedureName", 
                                new
                                {
                                    ClientId = myClientId,
                                    CompanyId = myCompanyId
                                }, 
                                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

How to a declare the variable `returnedData` before the `using` statement so the compiler will be happy?

Comment: what stops you to declare your variable outside of using?

Comment: My not knowing I could declare `returnedData` as `dynamic`. I have not worked with the `dynamic` variables much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Query<T>` returns `IEnumerable<T>`, and `SingleOrDefault` produces a `T` from it, so `returnedData` can be declared as `dynamic`:

```
dynamic returnedData = null;
using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(SqlDataAccess.LoadConnectionString("TestData")))
{
    returnedData = db.Query<dynamic>(
        "StoredProcedureName"
    ,   new {
            ClientId = myClientId
        ,   CompanyId = myCompanyId
        }
    ,   commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
    ).SingleOrDefault();
}
Console.WriteLine(
    "ClientId={0}, CompanyId={1}"
,   returnedData?.ClientId
,   returnedData?.CompanyId
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple and straight to the point. I am assuming by using the `?` I am able to get a value if `returnedData` is NOT `null`, but not throw an exception if it is?

Comment: @webworm Yes, that's exactly the purpose. Since you are using `SingleOrDefault`, not `Single`, there is an implied possibility of getting `null` back.